# Using reflection to set properties from a dictionary

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, casting, windows-phone-8

I have an object with some properties and a dictionary which holds a temporary value for each of property. The key of this dictionary is a string with the same name of the property, while the value is an object.

What I want to do is to build a save method that reads the dictionary's keys and set the corresponding property to the value found in the dictionary.

So I thought about reflection but it's not as easy as I thought.

Here's a sample class:

```
public class Class{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Settings { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (string key in Settings.Keys)
        {
            // PSEUDOCODE
            get the property called like the key
            get its type
            get the value of hte key in the dictionary
            cast this object to the property's value
            set the property to the casted object
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I'm not posting my code is beacuse I don't understand how to do casting and similar stuff, so I wrote a little bit of pseudocode to let you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Is there anyone that can point me to the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you keep the values in the dictionary instead. just implement your properties like `public string Property1 { get { return (string)Settings["Property1"]; } set { Settings["Property1"] = value; }}`

Comment: The properties are used for binding, the dictionary is used to give the user the chance of editing them and undo it. So the dictionary will overwrite the properties only if the user confirms it, otherwise the properties are not changed and they keep the old values. Probably this is not the best way to do this, but this came pretty easy in my mind.

Comment: Sounds more like you should implement deep copy/clone and let the user edit a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
//Get the type
var type= this.GetType();

foreach (string key in Settings.Keys) 
{
    //Get the property
    var property = type.GetProperty(key);
    //Convert the value to the property type
    var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(Settings[key], property.PropertyType);
    property.SetValue(this, convertedValue); 
}
```

Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: It works, but the `ChangeType` method takes the object and then its type.

Comment: You don't even need to change types first as SetValue() expects Object anyways.  Just do `property.SetValue(this, Settings[key], null);`.